# Writing to .txt skipping lines and leaving white spaces java

Tags: java, writer, reader

```
   String newPurchaseOrder = dateStr + "#" + customerID + "#" + productCode + "#" + qty;
        try {
            String filename = "PurchaseOrderDataFile.txt";
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true); //the true will append the new data
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("PurchaseOrderDataFile.txt");

            bw.write("\n" + newPurchaseOrder);
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
```

Trying to prevent it from skipping lines when inputting to the .txt file

```
08/12/13#PMI-1256#DT/9489#8
16/12/13#ENE-5789#PV/5732#25
27/12/13#PEA-4567#PV/5732#3@
09/01/14#PEA-4567#DT/9489#1
16/01/14#EMI-6329#PV/5732#8


16/07/13#ESE-5577#ZR/7413#6
```

Input skips lines such as above

Comment: the way you state your question it makes no sense. tell us what is your input and what your desired output

Answer (score 1):

*what do you mean "skipping lines"?*  `bw.write("\n" + newPurchaseOrder);` will first put an empty line if that is what you mean, just transfer `"\n"` to the end.. `The following code works fine:`

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
class myWrite {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateStr = "test";
        String customerID = "1";
        String productCode = "100";
        String qty = "1000";
  String newPurchaseOrder = dateStr + "#" + customerID + "#" + productCode + "#" + qty;
  String newPurchaseOrder2 = dateStr + "#" + customerID + "#" + productCode + "#" + qty;
        try {
            String filename = "PurchaseOrderDataFile.txt";
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename, true); //the true will append the new data
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("PurchaseOrderDataFile.txt");

            bw.write(newPurchaseOrder + "\n");
            bw.write(newPurchaseOrder2 + "\n");
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

writes:

```
test#1#100#1000
test#1#100#1000
```

EDIT: Using the output you told me,

```
08/12/13#PMI-1256#DT/9489#8 
16/12/13#ENE-5789#PV/5732#25 
27/12/13#PEA-4567#PV/5732#3@ 
09/01/14#PEA-4567#DT/9489#1 
16/01/14#EMI-6329#PV/5732#8
```

I then added the line you told me:

```
16/07/13#ESE-5577#ZR/7413#6
```

which produces:

```
08/12/13#PMI-1256#DT/9489#8 
16/12/13#ENE-5789#PV/5732#25 
27/12/13#PEA-4567#PV/5732#3@ 
09/01/14#PEA-4567#DT/9489#1 
16/01/14#EMI-6329#PV/5732#8 
16/07/13#ESE-5577#ZR/7413#6
```

use my code it works fine and does what you want..

Comment: give me an example of what you mean .. an example of your data

Comment: 08/12/13#PMI-1256#DT/9489#8
16/12/13#ENE-5789#PV/5732#25
27/12/13#PEA-4567#PV/5732#3@
09/01/14#PEA-4567#DT/9489#1
16/01/14#EMI-6329#PV/5732#8



1/1/1#PEA-1111#AA/1111#11111n

Comment: the last one I added skpped a line

Comment: what do you mean skipped a line? how is your data initially and how do you want it to be ?

Comment: It saves the input in the text file 4 lines below the previous input

Comment: what was the previous input and what is the next input ? edit your post write the 2 inputs, the output, and how it should have been, or else nobody can help you

Comment: Still does not make sense.. i told you. Tell us how it was before, what and how u input it and how u want it to be

Comment: 16/07/13#ESE-5577#ZR/7413#6 was added. All the rest was already placed within the file. I'm trying to prevent the whitespaces im getting when adding to the file. I want the new input to be added underneath.

Comment: just tried it. it works fine. just use my code don't make it a bigger deal than it really is...